# Check if substring is in a string in a different DF, if it is then return value from another row

Tags: pandas, match, isin

I want to check is a substring from **DF1** is in **DF2**. If it is I want to return a value of a corresponding row.

**DF1**

| Name | ID | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | AAA | A |
| John | AAA | B |
| Pat | CCC | C |
| Sandra | CCC | D |
| Paul | DD | E |
| Sandra | R9D | F |
| Mia | dfg4 | G |
| Kim | asfdh5 | H |
| Louise | 45gh | I |

**DF2**

| Name | ID | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | AAAxx1 | Microsoft |
| John | AAAxxREG1 | Microsoft |
| Michael | BBBER4 | Microsoft |
| Pat | CCCERG | Dell |
| Pat | CCCERGG | Dell |
| Paul | DFHDHF | Facebook |

**Desired Output**

Where ID from DF1 is in the ID column of DF2 I want to create a new column in DF1 that matches the company

| Name | ID | Region | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | AAA | A | Microsoft |
| John | AAA | B | Microsoft |
| Pat | CCC | C | Dell |
| Sandra | CCC | D |  |
| Paul | DD | E |  |
| Sandra | R9D | F |  |
| Mia | dfg4 | G |  |
| Kim | asfdh5 | H |  |
| Louise | 45gh | I |  |

I have the below code that determines if the ID from DF1 is in DF2 however I'm not sure how I can bring in the company name.

`DF1['Get company'] = np.in1d(DF1['ID'], DF2['ID'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find `ID` string from `df1` into `df2` then `merge` on this column:

```
key = df2['ID'].str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(df1['ID'].values)})", expand=False)
df1 = df1.merge(df2['Company'], left_on='ID', right_on=key, how='left').fillna('')
print(df1)

# Output:
    Name    ID    Company
0   John   AAA           
1  Peter   BAB  Microsoft
2   Paul  CCHF     Google
3  Rosie   R9D
```

Details: create a regex from `df1['ID']` to extract partial string from `df2['ID']`:

```
# Regex pattern: try to extract the following pattern
>>> fr"({'|'.join(df1['ID'].values)})"
'(AAA|BAB|CCHF|R9D)'

# After extraction
>>> pd.concat([df2['ID'], key], axis=1)
        ID    ID
0    AEDSV   NaN  # Nothing was found
1   123BAB   BAB  # Found partial string BAB
2  CCHF-RB  CCHF  # Found partial string CCHF
3     YYYY   NaN  # Nothing was found
```

**Update**:

> To solve this I wonder is it possible to merge based on 2 columns. e.g merge on Name and ID?

```
key = df2['ID'].str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(df1['ID'].values)})", expand=False)
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Name', 'Company']], left_on=['Name', 'ID'], 
               right_on=['Name', key], how='left').drop_duplicates().fillna('')
print(df1)

# Output:
      Name      ID Region    Company
0     John     AAA      A  Microsoft
2     John     AAA      B  Microsoft
4      Pat     CCC      C       Dell
6   Sandra     CCC      D           
7     Paul      DD      E           
8   Sandra     R9D      F           
9      Mia    dfg4      G           
10     Kim  asfdh5      H           
11  Louise    45gh      I
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain how the code is working.

Comment: I updated my answer. Do you need some explanation about `merge` too?

Comment: Nope that is perfect, thanks very much

Comment: I will. Just one more thing. I am using different DFs to the ones mentioned above. When I merge the DF gets alot bigger (more rows), how can I avoid this

Comment: I can't reproduce a such case. Can you update your post with more data, please? I'll look that later.

Comment: I have updated the data above. This will reproduce the duplicates. To solve this i wonder is it possible to merge based on 2 columns. e.g merge on Name and ID?

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. I do have another question on another DF.  is there ways to merge columns where rows are not unique without creating duplicates. For example I have 2 DFs; DF1 has a Name, ID and Region column some of the Names and IDs are the same but the regions are different for each. DF2 has Name and ID and Company how can I merge the company column to DF1 without duplicates. It might also be useful to note that the DFs are of different shapes. Many thanks this is my last question

Comment: I have updated the data to reflect above comments.

Comment: I updated my answer again. How Sandra is set to 'Dell'?

Comment: error on my behalf. she shouldn't be set to dell